# Get only post terms for Woocommerce product tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product

My function outputs all used Woocommerce product tags, on every product.

How can I sort out/output only tags that every single product has selected from backend?

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags',  5 );

function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
    global $post, $product;
        if ( is_array (get_terms( 'product_tag' ))) {
           $tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' , 'orderby=id' );
           echo '<span class="badge-cloud">';
           foreach($tags as $tag) {
              echo '<span rel="tag" class="fl-badge '.$tag->slug.'"><p>'.$tag->name.'</p></span>';
           } 
           echo '</span>';
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is o use [**`wp_get_post_terms()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) where you can set the post ID for a given taxonomy to get the terms for this specific post ID. So your code should be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags',  5 );
function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
    global $post;

    $taxonomy = 'product_tag';
    $args = 'orderby=id';
    $product_tags = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, $args );

    if ( count($product_tags) > 0 ){
        echo '<span class="badge-cloud">';
        foreach( $product_tags as $term )
            echo '<span rel="tag" class="fl-badge '.$term->slug.'"><p>'.$term->name.'</p></span>';
        echo '</span>';
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme or in any plugin file).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Cool, thanks you! Is it good / necessary "escape" anything or is all already safe / escaped by default?

Comment: @RawTom I don't think you need to escape or sanitize anything as nothing is submitted… It should just works nice as it is.